# Import multiple MetaGraphDefs into a single graph and restore variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

Similar question as [TensorFlow: Restoring Multiple Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098743/tensorflow-restoring-multiple-graphs) but using the tf.train.import_meta_graph() interface.

My code:

```
    with self.graph.as_default(), tf.device(device):
        with tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=self.tf_config) as sess:

            # Add inherited graphs to CenterNet's graph.
            self.mm_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.maskmaker.model_ckpt + ".meta")
            self.dv_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.deepvar.model_ckpt + ".meta")

            # First saver can restore
            self.mm_saver.restore(sess, self.maskmaker.model_ckpt)
            # Second saver raises an exception
            self.dv_saver.restore(sess, self.deepvar.model_ckpt)
```

Exception (without traceback, which was very very long).

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:
Key classifier/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at /home/markemus/dev/IHC/ihc/neuralnets.py:936)  = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

It looks like dv_saver is trying to restore all the variables on the graph, not just its own. The key that's failing, "classifier/bias", is part of mm's graph originally.

How do I restrict it to restoring its own keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! The Saver adds ops to the graph, and since both Savers were in the same name_scope they were interfering with one another. You need to wrap each call to import_meta_graph in its own name_scope:

```
with self.graph.as_default(), tf.device(device):
    with tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=self.tf_config) as sess:

        # Add inherited graphs to CenterNet's graph.
        with tf.name_scope(self.maskmaker.name):
            self.mm_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.maskmaker.model_ckpt + ".meta")
        with tf.name_scope(self.deepvar.name):
            self.dv_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.deepvar.model_ckpt + ".meta")

        # First saver can restore
        self.mm_saver.restore(sess, self.maskmaker.model_ckpt)
        # Second saver can also restore
        self.dv_saver.restore(sess, self.deepvar.model_ckpt)
```

Comment: The scope name may also be passed directly as an argument to import_meta_graph().